# gcc bug? It inexplicably decays array to pointer, while clang does not

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, c++14, clang++

This is a simplified version which illustrate the problem:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;

    template <std::size_t N>
    Foo(const char(&)[N]) {}
};

template <std::size_t N>
auto foo(const char (&arr)[N]) -> Foo
{
    return arr;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    foo("Stack Overflow");
}
```

g++ seems to decay `arr` to `const char *`, although an array reference argument is passed to an array reference parameter . It gives this error:

> In instantiation of `Foo foo(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned
>   int N = 4ul]`:
>
> error: could not convert `(const char*)arr` from `const char*` to
>   `Foo`
>
> ```
>  return arr;
>         ^
> ```

While clang++ behaves how I expect and compiles the code.

The code compiles fine on gcc with any of those modifications:

```
return {arr};
return Foo(arr);
return (Foo)arr;
return static_cast<Foo>(arr);
```

Is it a gcc bug?

Tried it with <del>all</del> g++ and clang++ versions which support `c++14`.(*)

(*) I just tried it with a snapshot of `gcc 6` and it compiles OK. So it does look like a bug fixed in `gcc 6`

Comment: Looks like premature decay.  Because you cannot return an array, obviously.  ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug in GCC where arrays would decay into pointers prematurely and the converting constructor would no longer appear to be a viable candidate. Examples similar to yours (and the eventual fix) can be found in the comments of these two bug reports:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41426
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66895